# Detect objects to be deleted from Realm database

Tags: java, android, realm

In my project I'm using Realm for storing data from API.
Before updating objects to Realm I'd like to check which objects are new (doesn't exist in database) and which objects should be deleted (exist in database, but don't exist in API response).

For checking new objects I'm iterating through API response and using simple Realm query to check which object is new

```
for(Follower follower: results.data){
      Follower followerFromDb = realm.where(Follower.class).equalTo("id", follower.id).findFirst();
        if(followerFromDb == null){
            Log.d("REALM", "Object is not in the DB");
        }
}
```

My problem is - how to efficiently check which objects should be deleted from the database.

Comment: Classic synchronization problem. An ideal solution would be making your backend notifying your app when an item is deleted so the app can update its local db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a pretty nice trick for deleting objects not in API response, which is that I add an indexed field called `@Index private boolean isBeingSaved;` to my RealmObject:

```
public class Thingy extends RealmObject {
    //...
    @Index
    private boolean isBeingSaved;
}
```

Then as I map the API response to RealmObjects, I set this to `true`:

```
ApiResponse apiResponse = retrofitService.getSomething();
Thingy thingy = new Thingy();
thingy.set/*...*/;
thingy.setIsBeingSaved(true);
realm.insertOrUpdate(thingy);
```

Afterwards, you've set each of these to `true` for the new elements. So you can do a deletion for all that is false.

```
realm.where(Thingy.class)
     .equalTo(ThingyFields.IS_BEING_SAVED, false)
     .findAll()
     .deleteAllFromRealm();
```

Then you'll need to iterate the remaining objects and set their boolean field to `false`

```
for(Thingy thingy: realm.where(Thingy.class).findAll()) {
    thingy.setIsBeingSaved(false);
}
```

And it works!

I do not know of a more optimized solution unfortunately, I can clearly see that this is `O(N)` because of iteration at the end. But you can follow https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/762 for bulk update support.

---

In your particular case, the special flag is `isBeingSaved`, and I guess you don't want to immediately delete them, but this is how I did it when I needed this functionality.

Comment: Nice trick buddy! but does this answer has updated in light of newer developments? Its been one year already, so was wondering!

Comment: also what should be done in case we are fetching paginated results? One way would be to use a flag called allowDeletion?

Comment: The tricky thing with paginated API is that it depends on how the API is designed and how you can know if an item is deleted. Is it just not in the list? Do they include the IDs of the deleted items? Maybe they have an "updatedAt" field with which you can guess that if you have a page from this to this interval, then if this existing item is not in it, then it should be deleted? it depends on API. I don't know of a better way than this trick at this time, it is unfortunate that batch/bulk updates weren't included. That would have made it more performant.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're database only contains data from the API, and local data is defunkt when an api call response is returned. If that's the case then you can simply delete everything in your database, and add everything from the api response into your `Realm`.

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
     public void execute(Realm realm) {
         realm.deleteAll(); //Delete everything
         object.delete(); //Delete specific object
         realm.delete(RealmModel) //Delete all of specific type
     }
}
```

Remember to close your realm when you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that I can delete everything or specific object but that's not the point of my problem.

Comment: Can you explain it better? To me, if you are deleting all of you local db rows that don't exist in the API response, then it sounds like you can just delete everything, and save the api response to the db. It'll be faster to do that, then to iterate over your current objects, and only delete the ones you want, before saving everything the API response.

Comment: I'd like to know what rows should be deleted because I don't want to delete them. I want to set a special flag for this rows.

Comment: Please note that this answer invalidates existing links.

Comment: Every time you do a bulk delete, your notifications block gets fired and will result in bad UI/UX. (modifying on every API response coming in).